# Embedded Signing EU Qualified IDnow TSP: Change email address of signer without him having to reidentify?

Tags: docusignapi

So we've implemented the DocuSign REST API for an European Qualified Electronic Signature (QES) using the IDnow TSP (`docusign_eu_qualified_idnow_tsp`).
Everything works flawlessly, however I am wondering how exactly a signer is re-identified using embedded signing on his next envelope. Let me explain:

When we create a new envelope, we set the `name`, `email`, `recipientId` and `clientUserId` of the signer within the request. When every value stays the same, the signer is successfully re-identified on the next document, so he doesn't have to create his signature again and doesn't have to go through the video identification of IDnow again.

However,  we're now at a point where we would need to change the email address of one of the signers. When we change the email on our side however, the signer isn't re-identified on the next documents. The name and clientUserId are still the same, only the email changed. So I suppose the email is a crucial element here, next to the clientUserId.

Is there any way we can change the e-mail address without the signer having to reidentify through IDnow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand this, in general in DocuSign, the name+email combination is used to determine if a user is identified as the same user or a different user. So, when you change the email address - that is a new user, even if the name and clientUserId are the same.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. Too bad though.